# C++ Partial Specialization ( Function Pointers )

Tags: c++, specialization, partial-specialization

Can any one please tell, whether below is legal c++ or not ?

```
template < typename s , s & (*fn) ( s * ) > 
class c {};
```

// partial specialization

```
template < typename s , s & (*fn) ( s * ) > 
class c < s*, s* & (*fn)(s**)  {};
```

> g++ ( 4.2.4) error: a function call
>   cannot appear in a constant-expression
>   error: template argument 2 is invalid

Although it does work for explicit specialization

```
int & func ( int * ) { return 0; }
template <> class c < int , func> class c {};
```

Comment: Your 2nd code snippet is missing a trailing ">" BTW.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you mean

```
template < typename s , s & (*fn) ( s * ) > 
class c {};

// partial specialization
template < typename s , s & (*fn) ( s * ) > 
class c < s*, fn >  {};
```

Comment: Actually, I want to specialize second argument on the basis of first type ? Does it make sense ?

Comment: @Shaikh: That's exactly what James's answer does. What's confusing you?